# Countif for filtered rows

Tags: excel

Trying to count yes values in a column with autofiltered rows.  Countif  gives me result for total range and does not adjust to filtered rows like subtotal.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:  Adjust the range to reflect the appropriate column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A2:A20,ROW(A2:A20)-ROW(A2),0,1))*(A2:A20="Yes"))
```